# how to set the variable in the ReactDOM.render?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Now I have the page Hello and I can get the name at the interface,
But how can I set the interface's name at ***ReactDOM.render***?

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Hello/>,
    document.querySelector('#root')
)
```

```
import React from 'react';

export interface HelloProps {
    name?: string;
}

export class Hello extends React.Component<HelloProps> {
    public render(): React.ReactNode {
        const name = this.props.name ?? 'Mr. Unknown';
        return (
            <h1>Hello {name} in Electron!</h1>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the name just for the example's purpose? Because otherwise you don't need it in your example, just directly interpolate `this.props.name ?? 'Mr. Unknown'` in your JSX.

Answer (score 2):

The following should work:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Hello name={'Kirby'}/>,
    document.querySelector('#root')
)
```

Note that you can pass a variable there instead of a string, or you can change it to the following:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Hello name="Kirby" />,
    document.querySelector('#root')
)
```